# Web site: navigation bar

Tags: java, jsf, jakarta-ee, richfaces, primefaces

I'm creating a simple web site.

At the top there should be an image, directly beneath it should be a navigation bar.

Depending on the selection in the navigation bar the content should be filled (static for now).

I'm an experienced Java SE/ EE developer but my last web development is about 10 years in the past.

I think this should be quite simple and many web site have such a layout, including [RichFaces](http://www.jboss.org/richfaces).

Note that menus drop down when you hover with the mouse over one of the entries in the navigation bar.

I'm running GlassFish and I'd like to use JSF and CDI (Seam?) once needed. Maybe RichFaces or PrimeFaces on top of that?

How can I create such a navigation bar with this technology? I hope there is an existing component I can reuse?

Comment: http://www.primefaces.org/showcase-labs/ui/layoutComplex.jsf could be a good starting point.

Comment: Hmm, so you recommend using a menubar? It's similar, but looks - well like a menu. Is this the standard approach? Just using a (customized ?) menubar component of whatever framework or is there a concept such as "navigation bar" in web development? E.g. Jenkis is another site using such a layout and navigation bar: http://jenkins-ci.org/

Answer (score 0):

I'm not the biggest fan of RichFaces but we use it at my current workplace.

In terms of getting started, I agree with @Cagatay comment, a good place to start is the demo page for the technology you wish to use. The Richfaces site you linked has a link to their demo site for their features, find the feature you want and view the source and go from there. [This](http://richfaces-showcase.appspot.com/richfaces/component-sample.jsf?demo=dropDownMenu&skin=blueSky) is probably the closest thing RichFaces can offer that matches what you are looking for. But by the sounds of it you are after something a little better looking.

Also, I'm pretty sure the menus on the jboss.org/richfaces site aren't using Richfaces, only the RichFaces demo site is.

Comment: Can you tell me what issues you have with RichFaces? The reason why I considered it is because of the CDI Ref impl -> Weld -> Seam -> JBoss -> RichFaces connection. I though taking the frameworks from one vendor might cause less issues. But NetBeans hasn't great RichFaces support and with Eclipse I have trouble to deploy it to GlassFish. Besides the view JBoss tools provides looks complicated.

Comment: Hmm, you think RichFaces doesn't use its own framework to create its web site? That would be strange. I hoped such a navigation bar should be easy with RichFaces because they use it on there homepage.

Comment: Of course I looked at the demo pages of PrimeFaces and RichFaces before I posted here, but thanks anyway ;-)

Comment: I just don't like it from a aesthetic point of view. It is functional and does the job however.

Their homepage is housed on jboss.org, which is the home of many other projects. This site would be designed independently and then just link to the child project sites.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer Primefaces though the version I use(3) is in beta stage and has some bugs;
What you want could be easily do like this(one version):

```
<h:form>
        <p:toolbar>
            <p:toolbarGroup>
                <p:selectOneMenu effect="drop"  value="#{options.content}" widgetVar="sel" >
                    <f:selectItem itemLabel="First Content" itemValue="FirstContent" />
                    <f:selectItem itemLabel="Second Content" itemValue="SecondContent" />
                    <p:ajax event="change" update="contentPanel,contentPanel2" />
                </p:selectOneMenu>
            </p:toolbarGroup>
        </p:toolbar>

        <p:accordionPanel id="contentPanel">
            <p:tab>
                <p:panel rendered="#{options.content eq 'FirstContent'}">
                    First Content Chosen
                </p:panel>
                <p:panel rendered="#{options.content eq 'SecondContent'}">
                    Second Content Chosen
                </p:panel>
            </p:tab>
        </p:accordionPanel>
    </h:form>
```

Tell me if this is what you had in mind...
(If you use Primefaces 3.0.M4 with the namespace: `xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"`)